# Google Classroom push notification registration Permission Denied for Students Only

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to create a registration for push-notifications with Python `googleapiclient` for Google Classroom. My code is working for classes where the user is a teacher but is not working for when the user is a student in a given class. I've tried on gsuite and non gsuite accounts.

The error is `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/registrations?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">`

The relevant code is

```py
def register(self, courseId):
    body = constants.registration_body(courseId)
    o = self.service.registrations().create(body=body).execute()
    return o["registrationId"], o["expiryTime"]
```

where `self.service` is `build("classroom", "v1", credentials=get_creds(uid, db))`.

and `constants.registration_body` returns

```json
 {      
        "feed": {
            "feedType": "COURSE_WORK_CHANGES",  
            "courseWorkChangesInfo": {  
                "courseId": courseId, 
            },
        },
        "cloudPubsubTopic": {
            "topicName": secret.pubSubTopicName,  
        },
    }
```

I have also enabled all relevant API Scopes to remove that from troubleshooting:

```py
scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.push-notifications",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courseworkmaterials.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly",
    "openid",
]
```

I'm not sure if it is a code error since it works when users are teachers. Is this a limitation of the Google Classroom API?

Full code: https://github.com/karmanyaahm/google_classroom_discord_feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is intended behaviour:

Your code is fine, and this is working as intended. Push notifications are a tool to manage courses, not to be used by students, so it makes sense that only teachers and administrators can [create registrations](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations/create).

While not very explicit, the fact that a user needs to be a teacher in order to manage notifications is implied by the following statement, to be found [in the official docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications#overview):

> Your Cloud Pub/Sub topic only receives notifications about resources that you can view with the credentials you supply when creating a registration. For example, if the user revokes permission from your application **or is removed as a teacher**, notifications are longer delivered.

#### Reference:

- [Push notifications in the Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications)

Comment: Thanks for that. I had also opened an issue on Google's Issue tracker (before you had replied to this) and they also recently replied with the same answer. <https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170027521>